# How to place an image on the bottom right corner of an image that doesn't have a set size

Tags: html, css, image

Here is my html

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="something" class="avatar"/>
   <div class="edit_photo">Edit</div>
</div>
```

"edit_photo" has an image on it's background. the img tag dimensions is not set so it could be anything. But I want the "edit_photo" div to always be on the bottom right corner of the img. Is this possible with css? I can't think of a way to do this. the img tag needs to always be an img tag and I can't change it to a div.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container should be `position: relative;` and the edit_photo `position: absolute;` like this:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    /* inline-block for 100% of child width */
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid #ddd;
}
img {
    /* for 100% height of the container */
    display: block;
}
.edit_photo {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 10px;
    /* Some color */
    background: red;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: white; 
}
```

UPDATED DEMO WITH MULTIPLE IMAGES: http://jsfiddle.net/HYQLQ/3/

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be possible:

CSS:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

img{

    background: red;
    height: 120px;
    width: 250px;
}

.edit_photo{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: blue;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
 }
```

Here's a JSFiddle to see:  http://jsfiddle.net/gW9PK/

You might need to play around with the .edit_photo and nudge it up a little bit.

Comment: If you don't want the containers to appear inline, use `display: table` instead:  http://tinker.io/a3a7b

Answer (score 0):

write this code in css

```
.container{
   position:  absolute;
```

}

.edit_photo{

```
 position: absolute;
bottom:0px;
right:0px;
widht:20px;
height:20px;
```

}

Comment: This won't work with the img being any size since the parent .container is a block element and the image inside of it is a inline element.

Answer (score 0):

`edit_photo
{
bottom:-600
top:30px;
right:5px;
}`

play with the numbers.